# Login redirect to custom domain other than the one which requested

Tags: identityserver3

I have a unique scenario where my users come from myapp.com, then they would be redirected to idsvr login and we have a custom field for entering district code and then after they login they need to be redirected to districtcode.myapp.com. Users will not be going directly to districtcode.myapp.com, so they don't actually come from that domain. So can I use idsvr for this scenario.

The only way that I can think of is after they login send them back to myapp.com where they came from with districtcode as a claim and redirect them back to districtcode.myapp.com and also register districtcode.myapp.com as a valid redirecturi?

Is this the way I have to go with? or is there any other approach that I can take?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you need a "district code neutral" redirect URI to go back to.

If you can set a domain for "districtcode.myapp.com" from "myapp.com" - then you could do the signin centrally - otherwise you need to go back to idsrv for another round.